# OAUTH_DISALLOWED_SCOPES error when authorizing named credential

Tags: metadata-api, oauth2, namedcredentials

I am trying to create a named credential to authorize access to the Salesforce metadata API, as explained in this blog:
https://gscloudsolutions.com/tips-tricks/using-named-credentials-with-the-apex-wrapper-salesforce-metadata-api/

But I am unable to authenticate the Named Credential. When I save the credential I am prompted to login as expected, but I get:

```
Problem Logging In
We can’t log you in because of an authentication error. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator.
```

The URL shown is
`https://<my domain>.my.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=Remote_Error&ErrorDescription=OAUTH_DISALLOWED_SCOPES&ProviderId=<provider ID>`

The relevant part seems to be the `OAUTH_DISALLOWED_SCOPES` -- but I have triple checked all the settings and they all have `full refresh_token offline_access` as per the instructions.

The user is a System Administrator and I have added a permission set with everything that I could find that seemed relevant.

I have also tried it with the new style External Credentials and it has the same issue.

I'm out of ideas.... Any pointers would be super welcome!

Comment: I tried the instructions from the blog as it is and could authenticate the Named Credentials